# Choices argparse option with "-x" arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Customer asks for new argument in Python script which should have one of two values: `-l` or `-t`.

What is wrong in the next code and why it yield an error?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", choices=['-l', '-t'])
parser.parse_args(['-t'])
usage: [-h] {-l,-t}
: error: the following arguments are required: action
```

Comment: Why are you using `parser.parse_args(['-t'])`? usually you just use `parser.parse_args()` which will get the argument from the command line. Here it seems you try to force it. Maybe read the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/fr/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: the code is for sake of example. In the real script I use `parser.parse_args()`

Comment: Generally it isn't a good idea to use dashed strings as values, either for positionals or optionals.  As default `argparse` interprets '-t' or '--too' as a flag string.  While there are tricks to get around that, usually they aren't worth it.  Do you really need those `choices`?  Why not just 'l' and 't'?  If you don't like `argparse's` priorities, use a different parser!

Comment: One issue is a technical way to implement the requirement, another one - is to explain to the customer that requirement is not the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `-t` appears to be starting a new option. Arguments literally containing `-` can be handled by inserting the pseudo-argument `'--'` beforehand (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing)).

Within runtime:

```
args = parser.parse_args(['--', '-t'])
```

Or from shell:

```
python myscript.py -- -t
```